# I Need A Javascript Code That Will Place The Word "Search" In An Empty DIV Value Tag Using The id=

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I have no access to the html, I need JavaScript code that will add the word "Search" to the value="" that is blank for the input with id "ReportQuery".

How should I code it?

Here is the code below:

```
<div>
    <input name="data[Report][query]" type="text" class="input_firm" value="" onChange="this.form.submit();" onClick="if( this.value == &#039;Search&#039; ) { this.select(); }" id="ReportQuery" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

Comment: From this quetsion I can tell you really aught to read the documentation for jQuery. There is a huge section on selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: HTML has a perfectly fine `<label>` element. Disappearing, reappearing values that pretend to be labels are nasty and cause accessibility problems (as the "label" vanishes just before a screen reader would read it out).

Answer (score 1):

if its a div

```
$('div#idDiv').text('search');
```

if its an input (because you comment .value :S)

```
$('input#idDiv').val('search');
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked: <script type="text/javascript">
$('input#ReportQuery').val('Search');
</script>

Comment: The tag names are only necessary for supporting IE 5.5, if you don't mind canning support for a 13 year old browser then you can omit the tag names and the selectors will perform faster: `$('#idDiv').text(...)`

Comment: @JamesFreeberg Really though James, you should peruse the documentation for jQuery so you have an idea what it can do for you (which is a whole lot): http://api.jquery.com

Comment: i am glad it helped. Remember to mark it as the answer if you think so

Answer (score 0):

See this article, it comes with many examples and details:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml

BTW, this is about the "direct" JS way, no jQuery involved, e.g.

```
 oFormObject = document.forms['myform_id'];
 oFormObject.elements["element_name"].value = 'Some Value';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ReportQuery').val('Search');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9YS4/

A good place to start for learning jQuery:

http://jqfundamentals.com/